# Running execute-command on a Fargate task with env vars

Tags: bash, environment-variables, fargate

I have a Fargate task that I'm spinning up from a CICD process in order to run a MySQL database import. The container spins up fine and, on the task container, I can access the environment variables as expected. However, when I try to pass the command I need the build machine itself to *not* evaluate the variables (it doesn't have them), but rather pass them along in such a way that when the container *runs* the command, it expands the variables.

I'm not sure how to do that and everything I've tried has failed. Any ideas?

```
mysql_cmd='mysql -u ${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASSWORD} -h ${DB_HOST} -D ${DB_NAME} < '
mysql_cmd+="/tmp/${image_tag}-db.sql"
aws ecs execute-command  \
        --profile="${aws_use_profile}" \
        --region "${AWS_REGION}" \
        --cluster "${aws_ecs_cluster_name}" \
        --task "${task_id}" \
        --container "${aws_ecs_backup_container_name}" \
        --command "${mysql_cmd}" \
        --interactive
```

The `mysql_cmd` string echoes out such that it looks correct so I assume the variables are getting passed as a literal string that doesn't allow them to be evaluated on the container.

```
mysql -u ${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASSWORD} -h ${DB_HOST} -D ${DB_NAME} < /tmp/20240125.3-db.sql
```

Would definitely appreciate any thoughts on how to proceed from here.